# Calculate distance given constant acceleration and time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acceleration

How do you calculate distance when given the constant acceleration and time. No, I am not talking about S=vt+1/2at². You use this equation to calculate distance when constant acceleration is not zero. My question is how to calculate distance from for example 0m/s to 10 m/s in 5 seconds.

Comment: The formula you quote is the formula for constant acceleration, which is what your title says you're asking about. If you want an answer for varying acceleration, you should share what $a(t)$ you are interested in (not that we can't give an answer for an arbitrary a(t), but it would make clear you are actually interested in non-constant acceleration).

Comment: uniform acceleration; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration#Uniform_acceleration

Comment: Unless given more information, your acceleration is constant, thus making $\Delta d=\dfrac12at^2+v_0t$ the equation to use.

Answer (score 2):

The equation $$x = x_0 + v_0t + \frac{1}{2} at^2$$ will find the distance your object travels. Set $x_0$ to 0 and set $v_0$ = 0. the acceleration is 2 m/$sec^2$  best we can tell is that acceleration is constant. The expression for acceleration vs. time must be give to find the distance traveled for a non-constant acceleration.